# How to implement threading to run two bash shell commands in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, bash, shell, python-multithreading

I have to record a wav file and at the same time I have to analyze it with sox. I am using fifo type file for this operation.

So here I need to start 2 threads at the same time but even if I use the threads I am not able to achieve what I wanna do. Always one executing first and then the other. I want them to be in parallel so that I can do some stuff.

```
#this should be in one thread
def test_wav(self):
    """ analyze the data """
    bashCommand = "sox {} -n stat".format(self.__rawfile)
    while self.__rec_thread.is_alive():
        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        wav_output = process.communicate()[1] #sox outputs the details in stderr
        #do something and return

#this should be in another thread
def record_wav(self):
    bashCommand = "arecord -d 10 -c 2 -r 48000 -f S32_LE > {}".format(self.__rawfile)
    pid = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split())
    pid.wait()
    if pid.returncode != 0:
        raise RecordException("Failed while recording with error {}".format(pid.returncode))
```

I tried the following code to make them threads but failed(Always one executing first and then the other. I want them to be in parallel so that I can do some stuff).
imported `from threading import Thread`

```
self.__rec_thread = Thread(target = self.record_wav())
amp_thread = Thread(target = self.test_wav())
self.__rec_thread.start()
amp_thread.start()
```

EDIT: First its executing the record(it minimum takes 10 sec because of the option -d 10) function completely and then the test wav function. Its like calling them one after another.

Comment: What do you mean failed? Describe the output or the error

Comment: @OferSadan Always one executing first and then the other. I want them to be in parallel so that I can do some stuff.

Comment: I don't know what the `sox` command does but possibly it's running too fast to even matter if it's threaded or not? Add a `print('thread 1 started')` to the top of each function and check the output

Comment: @OferSadan Yaa, I added prints too for debugging. But as I said its calling one after another. First rec thread completed and then test wav thread. Sox does nothing except printing few prints.  And that thread has while loop

Comment: `target = self.record_wav()` _executes_ `record_wav()` immediately.  You want `target = self.record_wav` (no parentheses) instead.  That's a start.

Comment: @TimPeters Thank You buddy. Its working now :)
Post it as an answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... target = self.record_wav() ...
```

is *calling* `record_wav()`:  it executes immediately, and the program doesn't proceed until `record_wav()` completes.  You almost always want to pass a function (or method) object to `target=`, almost never the result of executing the function/method.  So just lose the parentheses:

```
... target = self.record_wav ...
```

Comment: A small doubt here, that I didn't find that in any documentation. Can you point to it?

Comment: `f()` always calls `f` - the context is completely irrelevant.  If you're not surprised that, e.g., the statement `x = f()` calls `f`, then you should be equally unsurprised that `target=f()` calls `f` too.  The `Thread` docs clearly do say `*target* is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method`.  `self.record_wav` is a callable object.  `self.record_wav()` is whatever the heck `self.record_wav()` _returns_.

Comment: It seems I was drunk :P Now I got it.  It's the basics of programming. I don't know how my stupid brain missed understanding it.

Comment: It's a pretty common mistake.  Unfortunately, I'm guessing _your_ `record_wav()` returns `None` - and `target=None` is taken to mean `Thread.start()` won't bother to run anything (see the docs for that).  To catch this mistake, it would be more useful if `target=None` raised an exception instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you probably use python3, you can use asyncio to run the shell command in goroutines way.

```
import asyncio
import sys

async def execute(command, cwd=None, shell=True):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*command,
                                                   stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
                                                   stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
                                                   cwd=cwd,
                                                   shell=shell)
    std_out, std_err = await process.communicate()

    error = std_err.decode().strip()
    result = std_out.decode().strip()
    print(result)
    print(error)
    return result


if sys.platform == "win32":
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(execute(["bash", "-c", "echo hello && sleep 2"]), execute(["bash", "-c", "echo ok && sleep 1"])))
except Exception as e:
    raise e
finally:
    loop.close()
```