# How to verify the stats of a fifo using sox?

Tags: python, linux, python-multithreading, sox

I record a wav file using the arecord and I will redirect that to a fifo using

`arecord -d 1 -c 2 -r 48000 -f S32_LE > myfifo`

but how can I get the stats of this using sox?

`sox myfifo -n stat`

gives

`sox FAIL formats: can't open input file myfifo: WAVE: RIFF header not found`

See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896935/) on how I am doing that.

What options I need to give to sox to ignore the header.
I wanna provide the header details as command line if possible.

Comment: I've copied and pasted your commands, and they worked for me. Samples read:             96000
Length (seconds):      1.000000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.179199
Minimum amplitude:    -0.157074
Midline amplitude:     0.011063
Mean    norm:          0.011798
Mean    amplitude:    -0.000868
RMS     amplitude:     0.016321
Maximum delta:         0.155426
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.010183
RMS     delta:         0.015230
Rough   frequency:         7128
Volume adjustment:        5.580

Comment: Hmm. I think ur missing that the file is a fifo and I am redirecting the output to fifo

Comment: let me know if there is anything else I can do. at the moment I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hmmm, open two terminals and in one terminal `mkfifo temp.wav ; arecord -c 2 -r 48000 -f S32_LE > temp.wav`  and in another terminal `sox temp.wav -n stat` This will produce that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sox should be informed that the file is a raw type.
use `sox -t raw`

Now let's solve the issue.

Create a fifo using mkfifo and then arecord something into it

```
mkfifo temp.wav
arecord -c 2 -r 48000 -b 32 > temp.wav
```

Now apply the sox on it.

```
sox -t raw -r 48000 -b 32 -c 2 -e signed-integer temp.wav -n stat trim 0 1
```

as it is raw you need to specify the rate, bit depth, channels, and encoding format.

Now it will work without giving any error.

Cheers.